# Geoserver generate web archive file

Tags: java, file, war, geoserver

I'm doing some changes in Geoserver source.

I used quick start guide from [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/quickstart/index.html). I done all steps in guide and it works fine. When I run as java project with  **web-app/org.geoserver.web/start.java** file , It works fine. But I want to produce war file similar to geoserver.war in geoserver releases.

I didn't find any documentation or example about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem with geoserver developer manual.There wasn't a spesific topic but thanks to geoserver developer Jody Garnett ,I found  [this](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/developer/programming-guide/ows-services/implementing.html) link. I could generate own war file with maven through this link.