# creating geoserver war by modifying source code

Tags: eclipse, maven, geoserver

I am trying to build geoserver from source code with some changes.
I had installed the following for build and add to path in environmental variable:
"C:\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin ;C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse\java-neon2\eclipse\eclipse.exe"
At command prompt to the path "C:\geoserver_build\src"(source code), I had run the following command and build successfully:
"C:\geoserver_build\src>mvn -DskipTests clean install -P allExtensions"
"C:\geoserver_build\src>mvn -DdownloadSources eclipse:eclipse"
After this I import the project in Eclipse and run the Maven build.
I navigate to gs-web-app > src/test/java/org.geoserver.web > Start.Java, after succesfull run as Java application start I am able to run http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/ and its working fine.
I had made some change in geoserver and change an png with modification located at "C:\geoserver_build\src\web\core\src\main\java\org\geoserver\web\img".
Now I want to make geoserver.war file with change I had made.
I had gone through "[Geoserver generate web archive file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851989/geoserver-generate-web-archive-file/18938153#18938153)", but not helped out.
Please suggest me the way to do in detail.

Comment: Did you try mvn install

Comment: @iant yes I tried but it's creating the original geoserver.war instead of amendments.

Answer (score 0):

The [developers' guide](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/index.html) does include instructions on how to [build GeoServer using maven](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/maven-guide/index.html).

It should be as simple as:

```
mvn clean install -P allExtensions
```